# Building Kivy Python app for Android with imported external modules?

Tags: android, python, kivy, ros

I have written a GUI for our robot using Kivy and it works very well on PC, performing as we need it to. We think it would be beneficial to have this working as an app on a tablet of some sort. However, the code for the GUI uses the `rospy` module (for ROS publishers and subscribers).

If I were to follow the Buildozer building method listed [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-android) , would it break due to the `import rospy` requirement? My question is basically this: Will building using Buildozer break if external, non-Kivy, modules are imported in the Python code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `rospy` to your requirements in the `buildozer.spec` file, and pip will take care of it.
`requirements = kivy,rospy`

Comment: Thanks mate. For anyone interested I will try this within the next week and update the result.